# SQLite - Python inserir dados automaticamente

Tags: python, sqlite

Olá, estou escrevendo um algoritmo que coleta informações de empresas pagadoras de dividendos. A coleta é realizada e monta uma table e até esse ponto tudo excelente. mas eu gostaria de salvar em um banco de dados e estou utilizando SQLite 3 Python. A tabela está perfeita, o problema está quando tento inserir no banco. acredito que o erro esteja no laço "FOR", mas ainda nao consegui desvendar.

```
connection = sqlite3.connect('dividendos.db')
con = connection.cursor()


def create_table():
    con.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dados (Empresa text, Tipo text, Data_Ex text, Data_Pag text, Valor text)')

create_table()

def data_entry():
    
        for empresa in tabela['Empresa']:
            empresa = str(empresa)

        for tipo in tabela['Tipo']:
            tipo = str(tipo)
    
            con.execute("INSERT INTO dados VALUES('"+empresa+"','"+tipo+"','DataEx','DataPag','Valor')")
        connection.commit()
data_entry()
```

Nao é retornado erros, apenas não esta salvando como deveria. será que consigo fazer apenas um "FOR" para ler toda a tabela, ir atribuindo e só depois inserir os valores no banco?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caso esteja utilizando o **pandas** para armazenar os valores do banco de dados, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

Importando os pacotes necessários

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
```

Simulando dados recebidos e criando um data frame

```
empresa = ['EMPRESA_A','EMPRESA_B','EMPRESA_C']
tipo = ['TIPO_A','TIPO_B','TIPO_C']
dataex = ['2019','2019','2020']
datapag = ['01-01-2019','02-01-2019','03-01-2020']
valor = [10, 20, 30]

tabela = pd.DataFrame({'empresa': empresa, 'tipo': tipo, 'Data_Ex': dataex, 'Data_Pag': datapag, 'Valor': valor})
```

Mantendo a estrutura do seu código para criar um db e tabela

```
connection = sqlite3.connect('dividendos.db')
con = connection.cursor()

def create_table():
    con.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dados (Empresa text, Tipo text, Data_Ex text, Data_Pag text, Valor text)')

create_table()
```

Com esta linha você adiciona o conteúdo do data frame ao banco

```
tabela.to_sql(name = 'dados', con = connection, if_exists = 'append', index = False)
```

Com essa linha você consegue recuperar o que está na tabela

```
back = pd.read_sql('select * from dados', connection)
```

---

Código:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

# simulando dados recebidos e criando um data frame
empresa = ['EMPRESA_A','EMPRESA_B','EMPRESA_C']
tipo = ['TIPO_A','TIPO_B','TIPO_C']
dataex = ['2019','2019','2020']
datapag = ['01-01-2019','02-01-2019','03-01-2020']
valor = [10, 20, 30]

tabela = pd.DataFrame({'empresa': empresa, 'tipo': tipo, 'Data_Ex': dataex, 'Data_Pag': datapag, 'Valor': valor})

connection = sqlite3.connect('dividendos.db')
con = connection.cursor()

def create_table():
    con.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dados (Empresa text, Tipo text, Data_Ex text, Data_Pag text, Valor text)')

create_table()

tabela.to_sql(name = 'dados', con = connection, if_exists = 'append', index = False)

back = pd.read_sql('select * from dados', connection)

back
```

Saída:

```
    empresa      tipo   Data_Ex Data_Pag    Valor
0   EMPRESA_A   TIPO_A  2019    01-01-2019  10
1   EMPRESA_B   TIPO_B  2019    02-01-2019  20
2   EMPRESA_C   TIPO_C  2020    03-01-2020  30
```

Comment: Na coluna empresa vai receber da tabela tabela[‘Empresa’]. Então dessa forma que vc colocou dá certo ?

Comment: Não entendi bem a pergunta... Eu adicionei no final da resposta um data frame de exemplo. É dessa forma que ele vai ser inserido e retornado. Caso seu data frame seja diferente, o código `tabela.to_sql` funciona, pois ele salva o data frame.

Comment: Eu atribui os valores das variáveis e ficaram assim: 
empresa = tabela['Empresa']
tipo = tabela['Tipo']
dataex = tabela['DataEx']
datapag = tabela['PrevPag']
valor = tabela['Valor']

mas no final final deu esse erro: ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2) into shape (19)

Comment: Do jeito que postei na resposta você já criou os campos no banco de dados, certo? O que o pd.to_sql faz é associar o nome das colunas as colunas da tabela. Então ele grava sem você ter que fazer essas atribuições em variáveis separadas. Você testou o código que postei? Caso tenha dúvidas poste seu dataset que eu tento te ajudar. Abraço!

Comment: Deu certo, ficou perfeito! E muito mais simples.  Agora só mais uma coisa, é possível sobre escrever ? Ao invés de adicionar linhas, ficar apenas as novas ? Ou melhor, so salvar se a linha não for repetida.

Comment: [Documentação](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html), você pode conferir os métodos e opções do to_sql. Neste caso ai você pode usar no lugar de `append` o `replace` onde está o `if_exists`. Caso a resposta tenha solucionado o seu problema, considere em marcar como `aceita`. Grande Abraço!